# Batch crash on set command?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, crash

Here's my problem:

```
:NNEEWW
cls
echo Where to save the file (Type "Desktop" or "Docs")
set /p SaveTo="Where to save: "
if "%SaveTo%" == "Desktop" goto DT
if "%SaveTo%" == "desktop" goto DT 
if "%SaveTo%" == "Docs" goto DC
if "%SaveTo%" == "docs" goto DC
goto NNEEWW
:DT
set Place=DE
:DC
set Place=DO
cls
echo 'Name your file [You can not add the following: \ / : * ? " < > |]'
set /p name="Name: "
echo echo off>>"Current.BAT"
echo cls>>"Current.BAT"
title Editing: %name%.BAT - Program Creator
cls
echo Editing %name%.bat [Type "Quit" to save and quit, Type "Help" to get some help with commands]
echo [@echo off has already been added, to get rid of it, type "echo on", without an @ symbol please]
echo "Please do not add ['>', '|', '<'] as they are not yet supported"
echo.
:2
set /p content="[-]: "
```

now whenever somebody types "Docs" or "Desktop" the program just crashes! I think it has something to do with the set command but I'm not sure.

Comment: after set Place=DE you want to do something to jump over setting place to DO. But that is not the issue. And Docs and Desktop are probably just getting you through the loop. Have you tried adding some echo and pause commands so you know exactly which line is crashing?

Comment: If you choose DT `place` will ALWAYS equal DO because you execute it after setting it to DE. Also `If /I` does case insensitive comparison (it's buried in Help).

Comment: @Noodles, told the user to read the help file in his last question.  I guess my advice was not a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of GOTO's use an IF-ELSE structure:

```bat
:NNEEWW
CLS
ECHO Where to save the file (Type "Desktop" or "Docs")
SET/P "SaveTo=Where to save: "
IF /I "%SaveTo%" == "Desktop" (
    SET "Place=DE"
) ELSE (
    IF /I "%SaveTo%" == "Docs" (
        SET "Place=DO"
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO :NNEEWW
    )
)
CLS
ECHO Name your file…
```